# NSDictionary Memory Leak as Class Var

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I have a class that records audio on iOS.  I have a class var of `audioSettings` that is a dictionary with the audio recorder settings.  I create this `obj` once when the class loads and then the `recordAudio` method gets called, I assign that dict to the audio recorder.  After the recording is finished I `release` and `nil` the `audioRecorder`.  Here is the code:

```
- (void) recordAudio: (NSURL *) fileURL {
    NSError * error = nil;
    if (!audioSettings) {
        //If no dict, fill it
        [self setDefaultSettings];
    }   

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:fileURL settings:audioSettings error:&error];

    //audioRecorder.delegate = self;

    if (!error) {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];

        if (!audioRecorder.recording) {
            [audioRecorder record];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Create Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Here is creating the dict:

```
 - (void) setDefaultSettings {

     audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                  AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                  AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                  AVSampleRateKey, nil];
 }
```

After the record is finished I set:

```
[audioRecorder release];
audioRecorder = nil;
```

So I can use it again without releasing the entire class.

Comment: What is your question? What here is a "class var?" Using accessors rather than ivars would make this all clearer, and avoid the under-retain you have in `recordAudio:` (as pointed out by Nekto).

Comment: What do you call a class wide var in obj c?

Comment: There are no class variables per se in Objective-C. There are static variables, which can achieve basically the same thing. Your naming makes it very unclear that `audioRecorder` is an instance variable and `audioSettings` is a static variable. It's better to use properties for instance variables and class methods for class (static) variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `retain` `audioSettings` in `setDefaultSettings` or use another allocation method or set the value via `self.` notation.

For example, replace your method with my one:

```
- (void) setDefaultSettings {

     audioSettings = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
              AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
              [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
              AVEncoderBitRateKey,
              [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
              AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
              AVSampleRateKey, nil] retain];
}
```

Comment: Should I create my audioRecorder on init and keep it, or destroy and recreated it as needed?  Or is that two expensive?  Can I create it in another thread.  Your answer worked using alloc and initwithobjecandkeys

Comment: As I don't see hiw are using `audioRecorder` and don't its content, so I cannot answer to be 100% sure. You can use Instruments and test performance, so you can select the most efficient variant